# Deployment of ClickOnce VSTO document-level Excel app for all users. Trusted location issue

Tags: excel, vsto, clickonce

I have released signed document-level VSTO app by ClickOnce. I use my own untrusted certificate. It's app distributed among university students.

On some computers we encounter a problem with trusted location, so the app cannot be installed there.

I found advices to set trusted location (even with subfolders) via Excel on end-user PC. It unfortunately does not help (even with PC restart). I have found advices to set some values registries which sounds a bit nerdy (as I got used to comfortable and direct release via ClickOnce).

**I would like to avoid preparing Windows Installer or buying trusted certificate.**

Any help? Thank you.

*VSTO is very powerful concept, but the deployment part is really frustrating (compare to old-school VBA from user view).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows adds a flag (kind of "lock") to my installation file, so it was not possible to install it (via click once). Once I got it is caused by this flag, I simply "unblock" the file and installation went smoothly everywhere.

[image]